# change UILabel width in UITableviewcell when switching to edit mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

I'm trying to change the UILabel width within a custom UITableviewcell when switching to edit mode as the reorder button is overlapping with the UILabel.

Comment: Did you add the label programatically or in interface builder?

Comment: @sbarow no it's in the xib file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways (in code or IB):

1. Use [autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).
2. Use [autoresizing masks](http://www.techpaa.com/2012/05/understanding-uiview-autoresizing.html).

Comment: Solved it using the autolayout

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know, if it´s in your xib file, Im afraid you can´t, unless you use autolayout. In that case, you can always assign a constraint like a property into your class and modify it straightaway but set the constant value. Take a look : drag the constraint to your code and modify it in the way you want.
It would be different if you dont use Autolayout, in that case, the app lifecycle doesnt allow you to modify a constraint in your app unless you have added the object programatically.

Hope it helps